# QGIS Coordinate System in Layout manager does not work

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layouts

[image: Screenshot of layout manager; coordinate system is set to the right one]

When i am trying to set coordinate system to my project it does not show the proper coordinates of the area. I never had this problem before, can anybody tell me how I can change this? I always used the right coordinate system for the whole time while working on this dataset.

Comment: It seem to be similar to this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/476015/coordinates-in-print-layout#comment777345_476015 ; try using an interval not in mm
....